# How can I record a video in my ASP.NET website using a webcam. I want to use DirectShow.NET Library for this

Tags: asp.net, video, webcam, directshow.net, video-recording

Can anybody help me with this.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Record a video using my webcam in my ASP.NET website.
2. For this I want to use DirectShow.Net library

If any body can help me this then let me know, I'll be highly obliged.
I have a working sample for video recording via a desktop application using c# and directshow.net library, but I want to make this in ASP.NET and c#. So let me know if anyone can help me.

Though I want this with DirectShow.NET but I'm open to suggestions.

Looking forward for a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET application cannot use DirectX on the client's machine.

Your alternatives are to use Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but there's no option to save a file with getUserMedia() , the only thing that can be achieved using this solution is to get access to my camera and microphone, but I'm looking to record from these input devices.

Though I have Red5 Recorder as an option. but I want to use DirectShow.Net Library, as Red5 installation takes too much efforts and no proper documentations are given for that too.
Still if you have a suggestion regarding getUserMedia(),or if you know how to record a video using this method, then I'll really appreciate it. Tell me if you have a solution.